# Triple Talaq Bill introduced in Indian Parliament

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law, india, divorce, religious-law

From an article in a leading newspaper:

> Mr. Shashi Tharoor said he was against triple talaq, already voided by the Supreme Court, but opposed the Bill as it **conflated civil and criminal laws.**

How does it conflate civil and criminal laws?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How does it conflate civil and criminal laws?**

It doesn't directly, but it criminalises a process that was until recently purely a civil matter.

The so-called triple talaq bill - now enacted as the *The Muslim Women (Protection of Rights on Marriage) Act, 2019* - makes, at [section 4](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_3_20_00069_201920_1565334896444&sectionId=49422&sectionno=4&orderno=4), divorce by [talaq](http://www.legalservicesindia.com/article/2324/Talaq-Divorce-in-Islam.html) a criminal offence:

> Any Muslim husband who pronounces talaq referred to in section 3 upon his wife shall be punished with imprisonment for a term which may extend to three years, and shall also be liable to fine.

However, all other modes of divorce, such as [The Dissolution of Muslim Marriages Act 1939](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/handle/123456789/2404?view_type=browse&sam_handle=123456789/1362) for example, fall within the gamut of civil law.